# Task could not find "AxImp.exe" when building project on Visual Studio Mac

Tags: mono, visual-studio-mac

I have a .net project that was built on Visual Studio PC and now I'm trying to build the project on my Mac version of Visual Studio but the project will not build.

I've reinstalled VC Mac and also installed dotnet-sdk-2.2.107-osx-x64 as well as MonoFramework-MDK-5.20.1.19.macos10.xamarin.universal

This is build error I get.

> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.20.1/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5,5):
>   Error MSB3086: Task could not find "AxImp.exe" using the SdkToolsPath
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.20.1/lib/mono/4.5/" or
>   the registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft
>   SDKs\NETFXSDK\4.7.2\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools-x86". Make sure the
>   SdkToolsPath is set and the tool exists in the correct processor
>   specific location under the SdkToolsPath and that the Microsoft
>   Windows SDK is installed (MSB3086)

Comment: No ActiveX controls on a Mac, this project is not likely to port well.